# resetting time and attempt in c# and mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to reset the time and attempt field in my table  when reach that time I want for example after 1 minute of restrict the user reset that two field on my table , I have this method for reseting that fields after typing correct username and password:

```
public bool reset_Attempt()
{
    msc.Close();

    MySqlDataReader mdr;
    using (MySqlCommand mcmd = new MySqlCommand())
    {
        msc.Open();
        mcmd.CommandText = "update login_attempt set attempt=0,time=0 where hid=@hid";
        mcmd.Connection = msc;
        mcmd.Parameters.Add("@hid", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = getCPUid();
        mdr = mcmd.ExecuteReader();

        msc.Close();
    }
    return true;
}
```

and this is my method for checking username and password and attempts:

```
public bool validate_Login(string username, string pass)
{
    bool check = false;
    MySqlDataReader mdr;
    MySqlDataReader mdr2;

    using (MySqlCommand mcmd2 = new MySqlCommand())
    {
        mcmd2.CommandText = "select hid,attempt,time from login_attempt";
        mcmd2.Connection = msc;

        msc.Close();
        msc.Open();
        mdr2 = mcmd2.ExecuteReader();

    if (mdr2.Read()&&int.Parse(mdr2["attempt"].ToString()) < 4) {
        using (MySqlCommand mcmd = new MySqlCommand()) {
            mcmd.CommandText = "select username,password from login where binary username=@user and password=@pass";
            mcmd.Connection = msc;
            msc.Close();
            msc.Open();
            mcmd.Parameters.Add("@user", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.username=username;
            mcmd.Parameters.Add("@pass", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.pass=pass;
            mdr = mcmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (mdr.HasRows) {

                if (mdr.Read())
                {
                    check = true;
                    reset_Attempt();
                    MessageBox.Show("correct");
                }
            } else {
                check = false;
                update_Attempt();
                MessageBox.Show("incorrect");
            }
        }
    } else if (int.Parse(mdr2["attempt"].ToString()) >= 4) {
        check = false;
        MessageBox.Show("You have been restrict");
        set_time();
    }
}
msc.Close();
return check;
}
```

and my method for checking time:

```
public bool remain_AttemptsTime()
{
    bool check = false;
    MySqlDataReader mdr2;

    using (MySqlCommand mcmd2 = new MySqlCommand())
    {
        mcmd2.CommandText = "select time,attempt from login_attempt WHERE time < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE and attempt<=4";
        mcmd2.Connection = msc;

        msc.Close();
        msc.Open();
        mdr2 = mcmd2.ExecuteReader();
        if (mdr2.Read()) {
            check = true;
        } else {
            check = false;
        }
    }
    return check;
}
```

and now I want resetting attempts and time after reaching one minute how can I do this?

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: So... um.... two very important things here. First, this password validation code is **NOT SAFE**. It's _never_ okay to store passwords in plain text, or even encrypted. Rather, an irreversible cryptographic (not md5) hash must be used. When someone tries to login, you also compute the hash of the attempted password and compare hash values. Anything else is _very bad._ Even testing/learning/proof of concept code should not do this. Really, it's better to lean more on the identity/authentication features provided by your platform of choice than trying to write your own authentication code.

Comment: Second, C#/ADO.Net uses a feature called **connection pooling**, where it's not good to re-use a single connection object throughout your application. You really are better off instantiating a new connection for most queries.

Comment: I now must have encrypt my pass i will do that later but now i have this problem

Comment: No, you misunderstood 2 very important points: 1) You do _NOT_ encrypt passwords. Encryption is not good enough. You must **hash** passwords, which is not the same thing. 2) This is too important to do afterwards. Too often, "do it later" becomes "do it never", and that's when the breach happens.

Answer (score 0):

My algorithm for this:

```
void Login(string username, string password){

  var user = //query db for user. Get: password, attempts = number of failed password attempts, lockedoutuntilutc = a date of when the user is locked out until; no login will ever work before this date

  //if the user is currently locked out, bomb out, don't increase the failed attempts etc
  if(DateTime.UtcNow < user.LockedOutUntilUtc)
    throw new Exception("You're locked out. Try again in {(user.LockedOutUntilUtc - DateTime.UtcNow).TotalSeconds)} seconds");

  //ok the user may make an attempt - is it correct?
  if(user.Password == password.GetHashCode()){ //or better hashing algo

    //correct; reset the attempt, record their successful login; leave the lockout date alone (it's in the past - who cares about it?
    user.Attempts = 0;
    user.LastLoginUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;

  } else { //login failed
    user.Attempts++; //increment fails
    user.LockedOutUntilUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(Math.Pow(2, user.Attempts + 1)); //lock them out for exponentially longer times the more fails they make
  }

  //save db
}
```

You can vary the timeout using maths; doing a number of failed 2^(attempts + 1) means the first time they're locked out for 4 seconds, then 8, then 16, then 32, then 64... they'll have spent two minutes trying to get in by the time they've got it wrong 5 times; that's pretty good in that it's not too penalizing a legit user that just forgot or is trying th handful they can remember, but it quickly penalizes brute forces. And you can also have your customer service guys either lock someone's account by setting a far future date, or you can have them unlock by giving them a way to remove the date so the user can keep trying

Comment: It is not helpful for my problem how i reset it after one minute ?

Comment: Set the lockout time to one minute into the future! (like "else if attempts > 3 then lockouttime = now.addminutes(1)" )

Comment: no no I mean after one minute of restrict the attempts and the time is saved in the table be rested

Comment: that's what this code does. You're thinking about it in the wrong way; don't try and make a timer that resets the attempts in one minute, just permit them to try again after a time that is one minute in the future. Read the code again, and the comments